# Linking to iOS 6 SDK and have iOS 7UI

Tags: ios

Starting February 1 all apps should be optimized for iOS 7. To achieve this apps should have iOS 7 look and feel.

Is it possible to link to older SDK (like iOS SDK 6.1) and still have the iOS 7 UI by making appropriate changes to the NIB files OR do we have to link to iOS 7 SDK to actually achieve iOS 7 UI?

Comment: It means you need to have a Base SDK of iOS 7. You can still support iOS 6 if you wish by setting the Deployment Target to iOS 6.x.

Answer (score 2):

As the term SDK stands for *Software Development Kit*, which includes *UIKit*. So you can find `iOS 7 UIKit` only in `iOS 7 SDK`. Now, as per look & feel, definitely you can achieve `iOS 7 UI` in `iOS 6 SDK`. But I don't think upgrading your `SDK` is more painful than tons of customization you might need to do with your app using iOS 6 SDK. Anyhow, choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

I think the check Apple will start doing on February 1st will be that you're using the `iOS 7` `SDK`. They wouldn't manually examine each app to see that it *looks* like `iOS 7`. But you're still able to target `iOS 6` or even `iOS 5` easily when using the `iOS 7 SDK`, they just won't be able to use the new features available to `iOS 7` on those devices. Also when run on those devices they'll retain the `iOS 6` or `iOS 5` looks.

It's important to remember, if you do use anything in your app that is only available in `iOS 7`, you'll need to do conditional checks to see that you don't try to use those features on versions prior to `iOS 7`. I don't think that's an issue based on your question, but I put it in here just in case.